# How to store and play interactive HTML5 content?

Tags: html5, video, learning, video-hosting

I am really having a hard time finding much information on interactive HTML5 services or best practices.

We currently have tons of HTML5 **interactive** elearnings produced in Captivate, Articulate, Canvas, and "other".  These are pure HTML5 folders that simply play on their own with or without their own playbar.

We are currently storing these in a folder on our site and they play OK - we iframe to the source just as we would a video.  I am really worried about both storage capacity and the amount of strain they put on our services going forward.  For a while we were hovering around 30-40 content pieces but this has shot to 200 with 300-400 more schedules in next 6 months.  These range from 5MB-100MB+, so it is literally like dealing with video.

I have researched several hosts and they all say they do HTML5 interactive... but they don't.  What is the correct way of storing and playing html5 content that is interactive?  Also we have tons of videos and would like to use one service.

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without being involved in your site. There are too many variables and we don't know what your servers are like or how they're set up. It's very broad and not answerable here.

Comment: @Rob - Tell me what variables you want to know.  I can answer whatever you want and I control everything.  I can also do whatever I want within a reasonable budget.  We have a really good dedicated hosting right now but the only issue with host is 100GB hard drive.  We can upgrade this but got me thinking that this kind of format shouldn't be stored like that.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board, opinionated and recommendations on services are considered off-topic. You will need to update your server, use a video streaming service, or use a CDN delivery network to full-fill increasing demand. Your find [hosting advice in our catch all](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements), or use our chat channel to ask such questions.

Comment: @SimonHayter - come on Simon this is a new topic that hasn't been broached on the site.  What do you want me to do to make it less opinionated than the 50% of the questions that have opinionated accepted answers?

Comment: A unique question doesn't not by-pass our guidelines and rules. Additionally, you are fixated on one reason, of several mentioned in the closure reason. Users can appeal a closure by visiting our Meta, or by voting for reopen.

Comment: @SimonHayter - I don't see how this has anything to do with your hosting advise link.   In fact I could have answered the hosting advice link far better than any of the answers on there.  This is about best practice on playing an html5 function that is not video convertible.  I could go into stream resizing and other things but wasn't trying to over complicate the question.  You have assumed it was hosting advice and you should understand better, being you are a moderator on the site.  Since you are the only person that voted to close it, I would like a specific reason so I can ask in meta.

Comment: Actually there was two other people who voted for the question to be closed, this doesn't appear because I reopened the question and re-closed, as I believe the question was too board, rather than opinionated (something that you are fixated on). Anyhow, comments are not for content disputes, if you are dissatisfied with my response, then please visit our meta and hopefully other moderators can assist you.